# keytool error: java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: signed fields invalid

Tags: openssl, pki, x509, keytool, keystore

I have a X509 certificate pem file I got from Mongo Atlas. I'm trying to import it into the keystore like so:

```
keytool -importcert -file X509-cert.pem -alias myalias -keystore mykeystore.p12 -storetype PKCS12
```

But I get this error:

```
keytool error: java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: signed fields invalid
```

My pem file contains a cert and a private key:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

So I separated them into cert.pem and key.pem and then tried adding them:

```
$ keytool -importcert -file cert.pem -alias myalias -keystore mykeystore.p12 -storetype PKCS12
Enter keystore password:  
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Public keys in reply and keystore don't match
$ keytool -importcert -file key.pem -alias myalias -keystore mykeystore.p12 -storetype PKCS12
Enter keystore password:  
keytool error: java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: signed fields invalid
```

I get a different error for the cert, but the same error for key. Either way, I'm stuck on these errors.

How can I import my X509 cert into my keystore? (I am doing all of this in a kubernetes pod)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the alias name was the same as my keystore alias, causing a conflict. So doing this fixed is:

```
keytool -importcert -file X509-cert.pem -alias someOtherAlias -keystore mykeystore.p12 -storetype PKCS12
```